# Submit data from first page to second page then third page load content second page

Tags: php

I have 3 php pages.

first page: search.php

secondpage: process.php

third page: load.php

The first page take user inputs and forward it to the second page which filters the input trough an algorithm. The first page is as follows:

```
<form id="search" name="frmSearch" method="Post" action="secondpage.php" target ="thirdpage.php">

  <p>
      <input type="text" id="from" name="txt_source" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="txt_destination" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="submi"/>
  </p>

</form>
```

As said earlier, the second page [secondPage.php] filters the result. Part of the code is

```
$source = &$_POST['txt_source'];

$destination = &$_POST['txt_destination'];

.... 
....
...
```

The output is in xml document tree format as follows

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
- - - - -- - - - - - - -- - -- - - -- - - -- - - -- - ....

The third page [thirdPage.php] should take the xml tag city displayed from the second page while third page load.

When inputs from form on first page is submitted, the second page is displayed. However, while using

header('location:thirdpage.php');

in second page to redirect to third page, the xml document tree do not load. So, i guess header('location:thirdpage.php'); is inefficient.

Can someone help please or give a hint. I need a way to redirect the page to third page without affecting second page content. thanks.

Comment: Are sessions what you're looking for? `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['variable'] = 'value'; ...`; If not you can use `$_COOKIE` Both tend to keep values to users across their visit.

Comment: Wouldn't the second page already replace the first page? Maybe I'm not seeing things clearly?

Comment: The second page role is to filter from database and display the data in an xml document format.  This process is carried out in background. And then the third page interpret the result from the second page graphically. My objective is to display the result on third page on another window, rather than displaying it on same window onSubmit.

Comment: can you reconsider the question please

Answer (score 0):

first.php

```
<form action="./second.php" method="post">
```

second.php

```
// do validation, afterwards redirect
header('third.php'); exit;
```

third.php

```
//print thirds' page data
```

if you want to "keep" the first page, instead of redirecting to third.php page, redirect to first.php, and in first.php you then include third.php (include_once('third.php');

Comment: the second page display result in XML format and placing haader in the page causes error.  I tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost given by yourself.

Just change your form to this:

```
<form action="second.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

This will open a new window, leaving the first one intact. The third page eventually gets loaded in the new window.

**Update**

When you want to pass transformed data from page2 (which is xml) into page3, I would recommend either:

- create a page with a form, add the whole xml as a hidden input field, and have it submit to page3
- dump the contents of the xml into a session variable or temporary file and have page3 load it from there.

Comment: can you reconsider the question please.

Comment: @GrimJov I've updated my answer ... still struggling to understand what you're trying to do, but I hope my update covers it